# How to echo specific data in loop with a condition specific to the last row

Tags: php, mysql, loops, accounting

For an accounting system, I'm using PHP & MySQL. I've two tables "GROUP" and "ACHEADS".

In the GROUP table, I have:

```
---------------------
| id (AI) |  group  |
---------------------
|    1    | Group 1 |
|    2    | Group 2 |
---------------------
```

In the ACHEADS table, I have:

```
-----------------------------------------
| id (AI) |  ac_head    | amount | j_id |
-----------------------------------------
|    1    | Something 1 |  2000  |   1  |
|    2    | Something 2 |  1000  |   1  |
|    3    | Something 3 |  5000  |   2  |
|    4    | Something 4 |  4000  |   2  |
|    5    | Something 5 |  8000  |   2  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I've joined the two tables as GROUP.id <<->> ACHEADS.j_id

Now I need to preview the data like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
Particulars               | Details | Total  |
----------------------------------------------
Group 1                   |         |        |
 Something 1              |    2000 |        |
 Something 2              |    1000 |   3000 |
----------------------------------------------
Group 2                   |         |        |
 Something 3              |    5000 |        |
 Something 4              |    4000 |        |
 Something 5              |    8000 |  17000 |
----------------------------------------------
GRAND TOTAL               |         |  20000 |
------------------------------------==========
```

#### Challenges

1. The table will be dynamic and will generate within a PHP loop (I'm
   using a WHILE loop)
2. Remember: it's a table and if I miss echoing a td, then the table will break up

#### Problems

- When I'm using the loop it's echoing the data on the Details td
  accurately. But the sum of the details row according to j_id is also
  echoing in each td

Preview here:

```
----------------------------------------------
Particulars               | Details | Total  |
----------------------------------------------
Group 1                   |         |        |
 Something 1              |    2000 |   3000 |
 Something 2              |    1000 |   3000 |
----------------------------------------------
Group 2                   |         |        |
 Something 3              |    5000 |  17000 |
 Something 4              |    4000 |  17000 |
 Something 5              |    8000 |  17000 |
----------------------------------------------
```

#### My thoughts

- If I can check whether it is the last data of the query, if isset,
  then echo the total amount with it's td. (But remember the
  Challenge#2)
- Does it require a foreach loop?

#### I failed

- I tried checking max(id), it works fine in SQL, but can't use it in
  condition within a loop.

(If you still can't understand me, then on the second phase, I'll post my code.)

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: Opps! it missed a line: I joined the two tables as: GROUP.id < > ACHEADS.j_id

Comment: use with rollover in sql statement to get sums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do 2 loops:

1. Fetch `id` from `GROUP`
2. Fetch `amount` from `ACHEADS` based on `j_id`

This would look something like (non-tested code):

```
echo '<table><tr><td>Particulars</td><td>Details</td><td>Total</td></tr>';

$total = 0;

$q1 = "SELECT id FROM `GROUP`";
$res1 = mysqli_query($q1);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
    echo 

    $group_total = 0;
    $j_id = $row1[id];

    $q2 = "SELECT ac_head, amount FROM ACHEADS WHERE j_id = $j_id";
    $res2 = mysqli_query($q2);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1)) {

        echo '<tr><td>' . $row2[ac_head] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row2[amount] . '</td></tr>';

        $group_total = $group_total + $row2[amount];
        $total = $total + $row[amount];
    }

   echo '<tr><td colspan="3" align="right">' . $group_total . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '<tr><td>GRAND TOTAL</td>';
echo '<td colspan="2" align="right">' . $total . '</td></tr>';
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

njk rockz!
It worked nicely. Thanks a lot, brother - it helped me a lot, I can't explain.
Here is my final code:

```
<tr style="background: #000; color:#fff;">
<th style="width:150px;">Particulars</th>
<th>Details</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Opening Balance</td>
<td></td>
<td>500000</td> <!-- till not dynamic -->
</tr>

<?php
$total = 0;
$se = "SELECT * FROM group";
$res = mysql_query($se) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $row['group']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<?php
$group_total = 0;
$se1 = "SELECT ac_head, amount FROM `acheads` WHERE `j_Id` = '".$row['id']."'";
$res1 = mysql_query($se1) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
$group_total = $group_total + $row1['amount'];
?>
<td><?php echo $row1['ac_head']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row1['amount']; ?></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
echo '<tr><td colspan="3" align="right">' . $group_total . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
</code>
```